# React render component inline with condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to render a Home component if certain condition is met.

I tried to use the [Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) provided by React.

My code looks like this:

```
import Home from './components/Home';

...

<Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
  {menudata === "Home" && <Home />}
</Box>
```

Apparently react expects a string after the && (conditional operator). The error I get is:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

My Home.js component

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Using React 18.2.0 with MUI.

Comment: How are you importing `Home`?

Comment: @DaveNewton import Home from './components/Home';

Comment: I think issue is in the export. Can for time being failed the condition. And see that if the error is showing or not

Comment: still your issue is not because of this, check this [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-silence-bld95j?file=/demo.tsx), no issue

Comment: check terminal and brower console for any other error message, if any

Comment: @MadanBhandari you are right, the code you wrote works fine :( that's the only error I see in console

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the Home.js file and now it works